# MSSQL - Log Memory Used - Query Store

Tags: sql-server, sql-query-store

I couldn't find any good documentation about this metric value on the MsSql Query Store.

Can you please explain us the meaning of this one?
Or instead provide a valid paper on it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found your question after writing a similar question at dba.stackexchange [What is 'Log Memory' in Query Store 2017](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/231682/21924), I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: Update my question did get answered

Comment: Thank you for the link to the answer!!